# Error Building Xcode Project after installing AFNetworking via CocoaPods

Tags: ios

I am facing the following error when I am attempting to build my Xcode Project after installing AFTNetworking 2.4.1 for iOS 7.1 via CocoaPods..

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
/Users/nnayudu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fuse-hksjwkrntgavgvflwlisdncfjobw/Build/Intermediates/Fuse.build/Debug-iphoneos/Fuse.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main-2A00476E021EE59C.o
/Users/nnayudu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fuse-hksjwkrntgavgvflwlisdncfjobw/Build/Intermediates/Fuse.build/Debug-iphoneos/Fuse.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main-31DB0C4487DDF7B.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Additionally in the file browser of Xcode, `libPods.a` and `libPods-AFNetworking.a` are red.

I have tried removing arm64 from architectures, building and cleaning CocoaPods multiple times and can not seem to get rid of this error. I also tried adding $(PODS_ROOT) to framework search paths without avail.

Is there a possible solution that exists for this problem?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no problem with the installation of AFNetworking and the error was due to a duplicate .xcodeproj file from past code hidden away in the project.